# Symfony remove command from console

Tags: php, symfony-1.4

I newer work before with symfony 1.4, and have now problem, I have many custom commands in console, I not need all this commands and want to remove, how I can remove ?

I mean that when I run php symfony I want saw only standart symfony commands

I search for any xml config files but nothing found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you no longer need those commands then you can just remove the code.
Custom commands are typically under **lib/task directory**.

If you want to keep the code but no longer want it available as commands then you can just change those classes so that they don't **extent sfBaseTask** (or sfDoctrineBaseTask, or other sfBaseTask derivate class).

If you want to keep the commands and it's just a matter that too many commands make the command listing too long for comfort, then you should just organise the commands with namespaces. You can do that within the configure function of the relevant task classes. (See the [manual](http://symfony.com/legacy/doc/more-with-symfony/1_4/en/13-leveraging-the-power-of-the-command-line#chapter_13_writing_your_own_tasks) for that.)